# Table of contents for only a section in iWork Pages?

Tags: pages, iwork

I have a master table of contents that works like a charm, and each section is broken out appropriately with page breaks v sections.

For each section, I would like to have another table of contents for only that section. Is that possible? I'm in Pages '09.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature isn't supported by Pages '09. If you want to do this you'll have to switch word processing programs or manually create your Master Table of Contents.

> Each table of contents (TOC) you create using a Word Processing
>   template lists only the content that follows it, up until the next
>   table of contents. If you want a master table of contents for the
>   entire document, it must be the only table of contents, and it must be
>   at the beginning of the document.

Source: [Apple's Pages '09 User Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Pages09_UserGuide.pdf) (page 64). The same information can be found using Pages > Help and searching for *Creating and Updating a Table of Contents*

Comment: Oh well, that's a shame.